# Texpad Live Vs. MacTeX Vs. MikTeX compiler differences (output files)

Tags: miktex, compiling, mactex, auxiliary-files, texpad

I am struggling with following:

I work on a larger collection in LaTeX, which includes around 30 different papers. I am used to work on macOS (Texpad - currently using live compiler), hence compiling via MacTeX. However, it does not produce files such as `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.log`, `.out` etc. and most importantly, supporting file generated by the template I have to use to set page numbering and order for each article.

After correction I have to recompile each article under Windows (using TeXStudio) to obtain necessary files. Is there a way to achieve this in macOS (I use Mac for all of my other work-related things and it becomes very unpleasant to need both systems).

Comment: All TeX implementations produce the `.aux` file, etc. Are you using a nasty IDE which automatically deletes them?

Comment: I've been using MacTeX for many years, and it's news to me that MacTeX doesn't produce .aux, .bbl, .log, .out etc files along with a pdf file. Please tell us more about your computing setup. (FWIW, I run MacTeX2020, with all updates applied.)

Comment: If you're using MacOS, then use an IDE that works with it. TeXStudio is cross-platform, so why not use it if you're used to it. I don't know much about TeXpad, but I don't think it uses MacTeX directly, and it may be hiding `.aux` files in a folder you can't see.

Comment: @Mico I currently use live typesetter provided by Texpad (1.8.17) to save some memory. It only provides me with .tex and .pdf file.

Comment: Check the command your editor is using to compile your code. Perhaps it's hiding aux files, or deleting them. Like @IanThompson said, all TeX distributions produces these files.

Comment: In TeX studio, I go to `Options > Configure TeX studio > Commands`, it should be similar.

Comment: The MacTeX distribution comes with two IDEs: TeXworks and TeXshop. Learn how to use one (or both) of them. Or, study the posting [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5001) for additional options.

Comment: Looking at the TeXPad documentation [here](https://www.texpad.com/docs/apps/settings/preferences#3-editor-preferences) it hides `.aux` files by default, but you can change this in the preferences.

Comment: @IanThompson and AlanMunn I don't know, maybe. Texpad 1.8.17 as I mentioned previously. 

There is an option to "hide intermediate files", which should keeps the working directory uncluttered with only .tex and .pdf (description), but I have it unchecked.

Comment: @Mico --- Delete all IDEs and compile documents, Fortran programs and everything else using the terminal!

Comment: Then the question may be better aimed at the TeXpad support people, rather than here.

Comment: Again, these files *are not* related to the editor. It's TeX-inherent. Try running the Mac equivalent of `ls -la` (I think it's the same) in the folder you're working. Maybe it reveals some hidden folder that contains your aux files.

Comment: According to the documentation sent by @Mico, you should find your files in `./.texpadtmp`.

Comment: I have already changed the thread name - including Texpad (I though that a live compilation is based on MacTeX as the most common typesetter for macOS, but I was probably wrong - my compiler is **TexpadTex + Bibliography**, according to the Texpad, I apologize for the confusion).

Comment: I haven't used TeXpad, but I suspect that the presence of a `.texpadtmp` directory is sufficient to hide the files independent of the preference setting. If that's the case, try deleting all the aux files and recompiling and see if they appear, and failing that, delete the `.texpadtmp` directory entirely and then recompile.

Comment: @AlanMunn This may be a noob question, but I cannot locate the `.texpadtmp` directory. It's not under root user's files or in my LaTeX directory or in the library. I have once again looked at possibilities of Texpad, but there is no setting concerning these files. I will ask the Texpad guys themselves, I guess and see. I just hope that there is an option.

Comment: Folders beginning with `.` are hidden by default. The easiest way to see them is using the command line although there may be a Finder preference to show them. Open the terminal app and navigate to the folder where your .`.tex` source is, e.g. `cd ~/Documents/myfolder` if your file is in `myfolder` within `Documents`. Then type `ls -a` to list all the files in the folder. If you see `.texpadtmp` you can the type `rm -rf .texpadtmp` to remove it and its contents.

Comment: @AlanMunn Got it. After being in the final, typing `ls -a` showed only `.tex`, `.pdf`, `.bib`, and template files (`.cls`, `.bst`), _.DS_Store_ (macOS files), and _Figures_ as I always put figures for each article separately. There was no trace of auxiliary or similar files. By the way I did not mention that if I would recompile the `.tex` in Win OS, _Texpad_ won't delete them and even work with the template properly.